# Deployment with Docker tensorflow/serving fails when training the model on another machine

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, deployment

I'm following the Coursera [TensorFlow Serving with Docker for Model Deployment](https://www.coursera.org/learn/tensorflow-serving-docker-model-deployment/home/welcome) course.

You have to **train** a simple Tensorflow model and export it in **Protobuf**.

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, path)
```

Then you have to **deploy** it with Docker and the [tensorflow/serving](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/serving) image, as follows:

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 \ # Expose port 8500 for gRPC endpoints
           -p 8501:8501 \ # Expose port 8501 for REST endopoints
           --mount type=bind,\
           source=/path/amazon_review/,\ # Absolute path to the model
           target=/models/amazon_review \ # Where in the docker container load the model
           -e MODEL_NAME=amazon_review \ # Environment variable
           -t tensorflow/serving # Set the image to use
```

Everything goes well when the **training** and the **deployment** is *on the same machine*. However, when I train the model on the course machine and try to deploy it on my own Amazon EC2 instance, the deployment fails and I get the following error. The full stack trace can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/XN7U4veD).

```
2021-09-22 18:58:19.959241: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] 
Loading servable: {name: amazon_review version: 1631554979} failed: Data loss: file is too short to be an sstable
         [[{{node RestoreV2}}]]
```

The error is not related to the deployment itself, but the loading of the saved model.

Related but not solving the issue:

- [Loading Model from GCS Fails With Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number)](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1441)
- [Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2675)
- [freeze_graph inspect_checkpoint, Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7696)